# The below code is working in the console however, it is not working in suitescript 2.0. script giving an error "invalid quantifier ?" at line 7

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

//the taxhead and taxamt are mapped. I want to remove IGST:output from every element of the array for that I'm using regex but it is failing with the below mentioned error.

```
var taxamt=[150229.13,81123.77,100,100,50];
 taxhead=["IGST:Output IGST @ 18%","IGST:Output IGST @ 18%","CGST:Output CGST @ 18%","CGST:Output CGST @ 9% SGST:Output SGST @ 9%","CGST @ 9%"];
var temp=Array(taxhead.length).fill(false);
var taxheadtemp=[];
for(var i=0;i<taxhead.length;i++)
{
    let temp3 = taxhead[i].match(/(?<=gst:output)(.*?%)/ig);//error:invalid quantifier ?
    if(temp3 != null) {
        taxheadtemp.push(...temp3);
    }
}
console.log(taxheadtemp);
```

Comment: @avi. First of all thank. I figured it out that spread operator works in we use suitescript version 2.x , my script version was 2.0 and that is the reason it wasn't working.

Answer (score 1):

What is the script-type? I mean is it server side(eg. User-Event, Suitelet) or client-script?

If it is server side script, and you are using suite-script 2.0 and not 2.x or 2.1, [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) won't work, and instead you have to use [Array.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).